# system.data assembly reference

Tags: xamarin.ios, system.data

I am trying to reference `System.Data` in a MonoTouch application for the iPhone, but am getting the following error:

```
The type or namespace 'Data' does not exist in the namespace 'System'. 
Are you missing an assembly reference?"
```

I have tried adding a reference in the Edit References window, but cannot see it listed anywhere, or find it using the search option on the left side of the Edit References window. 
How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

From MonoDevelop look at your **solution** pad (left by default).

You should right-click the **References** (under your project) and select "Edit References...".

The dialog should show you some tabs, select the **Packages** one.

A list of assemblies should be shown. Click on the checkbox across the one named:

```
System.Data    2.0.5.0    mono-iphone
```

Then click **Ok** to close the dialog and rebuild your application.